# How to get the guidDeviceInterface via VID/PID?

Tags: winapi, usb, winusb, setupapi

I am trying to understand a [WinUsb Microsoft example](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/blob/staging/windows-driver-docs-pr/usbcon/using-winusb-api-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device.md). There is next code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
  GUID guidDeviceInterface = OSR_DEVICE_INTERFACE; //in the INF file
  HANDLE hDeviceHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE hWinUSBHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  ...some other variables...
 
  bResult = GetDeviceHandle(guidDeviceInterface, &hDeviceHandle);
  bResult = GetWinUSBHandle(hDeviceHandle, &hWinUSBHandle);
  ...some interesting actions with hWinUSBHandle. For example...
  bResult = ReadFromBulkEndpoint(hWinUSBHandle, &PipeID.PipeInId, cbSize);
  system("PAUSE");
done:
  CloseHandle(hDeviceHandle);
  WinUsb_Free(hWinUSBHandle);
  return 0;
}
```

But the OSR_DEVICE_INTERFACE constant occurs only one time in the whole example with a kind of self-evidence.

If I know the VID/PID of my USB device and the target endpoint, can I get the guidDeviceInterface with such code:

```
deviceInfoSet = SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(&GUID_DEVCLASS_USB, NULL);
allDevices = SetupDiGetClassDevsExA(NULL, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_ALLCLASSES, deviceInfoSet, NULL, NULL);
for(devIndex = 0; SetupDiGetDeviceInfo(allDevices, devIndex, &deviceInfo);devIndex++)
{
    SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceIdA(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInfo, devId, 1024, &devIdLen);
    if(...the VID/PID equality condition...)
    {
        ...getting the OSR_DEVICE_INTERFACE...
    }
}
```

If yes, what is the condition and what is the right action for getting guidDeviceInterface?